# VScode does not seem to accept interpreter from virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, remote-server

I am using the remote SSH option in VSCode to access a server, where I created a Python virtual environment.

The issue is that whenever I launch VSCode, it keeps showing the following error message:

[image]

However, when I click `Select Python Interpreter`, it shows me that my custom environment is indeed selected (the one marked as `Current`):

[image]

Additionally, I keep getting warnings that say:
`Import "package_name" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource` whereas `package_name` (e.g. Pandas) is installed in `env`.

I added the following lines to my `settings.json`:

`"python.pythonPath": "/path_of_my_home_dir/env/bin/python"`

and

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "/path_of_my_home_dir/env/bin"
]
```

but it's still not recognizing the environment.

Note that my code runs properly. It's just that seeing these warnings is confusing.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is the env shown in bottom-left corner as interpreter? Did you activate the env in integrated Terminal?

Comment: the virtual environment is the one shown as 'Current'. Yes, I activated the env but it has no impact.

Comment: Does the question still exist if you create another virtual environment?  If it does, try to reinstall python extension.

Comment: yes, actually this is the 3rd virtual env I've created. I tried reinstalling python extension but it's still showing "Select python interpreter" even though it's selected as shown in the screenshot above.

Comment: Does your full screenshot of vscode look like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/45497113/67699347-3ce47c00-f969-11e9-95b2-7b4a32761035.png)? There's no interpreter shown in status bar so there would be a prompt popping up to mention user to select it.

Comment: yes, and when I go to "Select Python interpreter", I get the second screenshot shown in my post (this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpz5y.png ). Note that I am not using WSL, though. I am using WSL for another project and I don't run into this issue.

Comment: Click the global python environment, can it be shown in the status bar?

Comment: yes, it's shown and the warnings disappear. However, now when I run my code, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_name'` even though the environment is activated, and the corresponding module is installed there.

Comment: Solve questions one by one, please try my answer to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I find similar issue in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8561) and one solution post by engineers is adding the following configuration in **User** Settings.json:

```
"python.experiments.optInto": [
        "pythonDiscoveryModule",
    ]
```

Then **reload window**.

Please have a try and see if the error goes away.

**[UPDATE]**

This seems to be a bug, you could comment that you've met the similar question under this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14935) or [put a bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose) by yourself to let engineers know and fix it.

Comment: So, I tried to do this in **User** Settings.json. However, I get `This setting cannot be applied in this window. It will be applied when you open a local window.` and those additional configuration lines remain grayed out. I also tried this in the **Remote** Settings.json and those 2 lines are no longer grayed out. However, it's still asking to select Python interpreter (even after reloading the window)

Comment: Then how about adding `"python.experiments.optOutFrom": ["DeprecatePythonPath - experiment"],` in your user and remote settings?

Comment: in User settings it's grayed out. In Remote, it's not. So now my Remote Settings look like this: `{
    "remote.autoForwardPortsSource": "output",
    "jupyter.alwaysTrustNotebooks": true,
    "python.experiments.optInto": [
        "pythonDiscoveryModule"
    ],
    "python.experiments.optOutFrom": ["DeprecatePythonPath - experiment"],
    "python.pythonPath": "/my_home_path/env/bin/python",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/my_home_path/env/bin/python"
}` But, still no change after reloading.

Comment: Got it, it seems to be a bug, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @sqlquestionasker. You're welcome. Do engineers in github reply to your question? can you share your issue link?

Comment: @sqlquestionasker, If you're blocked by this question, try [VS Code Insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) and see if it helps.